# visual studio 2010 with c# like namespaces in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to have visual studio 2010 automatically add namespaces to classes within folders just like c#?

Comment: I'm currently forced into a vb.net project. I really wish I wasn't...

Comment: I've always wondered why people have so many negative feelings about this great language.

Comment: @Darin, what's always puzzled me SO users who rail against VB.Net for being an unsafe language but are heavily active in the ruby tag.

Comment: @Darin, I have nothing against vb.net other than I prefer to use c#.

Comment: @JaredPar, totally agree with you.

Comment: @Jared: Pardon me, but how is VB.NET particularly late-binding?

Comment: @Steven, possibly a reference to vb.net defaults of having "Option Strict Off"?

Comment: @MyNameIsJob: Maybe, although I've never seen a shop that didn't require "Option Strict On".

Comment: @Steven, Agreed. Several projects that I'm currently looking at here and it Off by default and resulted in tons of errors to fix. Not fun.

Comment: @Steven, setting Option Strict Off and invoking any expressions on an expression of type `System.Object` results in a late bound call.

Comment: @Jared: Ugh, this brings back horrible memories of `IDispatch`.  As Job and I have been saying, it's a good thing this feature is immediately disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible with the VB.Net project system.  I would encourage you to share this opinion with the Visual Basic IDE team.  They closely monitor suggestions and I know this has come up in the past (although I don't know if there is a current outstanding request for it).

- http://connect.microsoft.com